# Syncing openGL rendering with c++ game loop on android

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, opengl-es

I am building a game like application using android NDK and openGL ES 2.0

So far I understand the concept of vertices and shaders and programs.

The main game loop would be a loop in a single thread as follows

step 1. Read all the user input

step 2. Update game objects (if needed) based on the input

step 3. make draw calls for all the objects

step 4. call glSwapBuffers

then loop back to step 1

But I ran into various confusions regarding sync and threading so I'm listing all the question together.

1.Since open GL draw calls are asynchronous the draw calls and glSwapBuffers may get called many times before the gpu has even rendered actually a single frame from calls from last iteration of loop. Will this be problematic? buffer overflow or tearing ?

2.Assuming VSYNC is enabled then does point 1 still causes problem?

3.Since all calls are async how do I measure the time spent rendering each frame? glSwapBuffers would return immediately so how can I know when was the frame actually done?

4.loading textures will occupy space in the ram is checking free memory before loading texture standard way or I should keep loading textures until I reach OUT_OF_MEMORY_ERROR?

5.If I switch to multithreaded approach calling just glswapbuffers at a fixed 60 times per second without any regard to the thread which is processing input and giving out draw calls then what is supposed to happen?

Also how do I control the fps in game loop? I know the exact fps depends on a large no of factors but how can you go close to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `SwapBuffers()` will not be executed out of order. Issuing it after all of the draw commands for the frame is fine. The driver will take care about it, you don't need to sync anything. You can only screw this about by using multiple threads or multiple contexts, but even that would take a lot of effort.
2. There is no problem with 1, and VSYNC does not directly change anything here.
3. The calls might be asynchronous, but the driver will not queue up an unlimit amount of work. Sooner or later, it will have to block, if you try to issue too many calls in advance. When vsync is on, the typicial behavior is that the driver will queue up at most a few frames (or just one, depending on the driver settings), and `SwapBuffers()` will *block* when that limit is reached. So the timing statistics you get there are accurate, after the first few frames. Note that this is still much better than completely flushing the queue, as the driver unblocks as soon as the first pending buffer swap was carried out.
4. This is a totally new topic, which probably belongs into another question. However: It is very unlikely that you get any of the current desktop GL implementations to ever generate `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`. The driver will automatically page textures (and other objects) between VRAM and system RAM (and the OS might even page that to disk). The GL also provides no means to query the available memory.
5. In that scenario, you will need to synchronize manually. That approach does not make the slightest sense and seems like trying to solve a problem which does not exist. If you want your game to use multithreading, still put all the gl rendering (and swapbuffers) into the same thread. You can use different threads for input processing, sound, physics, update of the scene, general game logic and whatever. But you should just use a single thread/single context approach for the GL. That way, it also won't hurt you when `SwapBuffers()` blocks your render thread, as your game logic and input handling is still done, and the render thread will just render new frames with the newest available data in the frequency the display needs (with vsync on) or as fast as the CPU and GPU can work (if vsync is off).

Comment: Ahh feels good to be informed. So is approach 1 is a good idea for a realtime game like application?

Comment: @Allahjane: In general, yes. Usually, you don't need to put effort into syncing swapbuffers. It takes more effort to sync (or avoid implicit syncing) in the case of updating dynamic data, like texture or vertex data streaming.